# React Redux - Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, state

I want to use the `useSelector()` hook but I'm getting the error mentioned above. Where can I use this hook to get access to my state data?

```
function RetrieveDataSources() {
  var dataSources = useSelector(state => state.dataSourcesReducer);
  console.log(dataSources);
}

class Data extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      errorMessage: false,
      isLoading: true,
      resultData: propsState && propsState.resultData,
    };


    RetrieveDataSources();
  }

 
  render() {
    return( some return code );
         }
}


export default Data;
```

Comment: `RetrieveDataSources` is not a component, it is a normal function. Hooks cannot be used this way.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks can only be called in either a function component, or custom hooks.
You are calling it from a normal function instead hence the error.

Furthermore, it seems you want to call a hook from a class component - that's unfortunately not directly supported. If you have to use class components, consider using mapStateToProps & connect apis instead to get it from your redux store.

If you still prefer to use hooks from within class component, [here](https://github.com/sidecus/authzyin.js/blob/977484b59e7215e6cb76e292d94b6b18b5ccbc0a/src/Authorize.tsx#L59) is an example to use function component and React render props to share it back with the parent component. This is usually done by libraries though where people cannot dictate whether the caller is using function component or class component.